# Force password for ssh login

Tags: centos, ssh, centos7, centos6

I have two servers with CentOS6 and CentOS7.

Both of them has SSH access. My client computer has Ubuntu 16.04.

For CentOS6 I can login with command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/serv1 root@serv1
```

but command

```
ssh root@serv1
```

prompts the password. It is ok for me.

For CentOS7 I can login with command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/serv2 root@serv2
```

but command

```
ssh root@serv2
```

DO NOT prompts the password. I can login successfully too.

When I do 'ssh root@serv2' from some another computer ssh prompts the passwords, it is ok.

The question is: why I can login to serv2 without password and without ssh key with command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/serv2 root@serv2
```

?

I can't find option responsible for it and can't find is this standard behavior for CentOS7.

Tell me if additional info needed.

Comment: Most probably the key serv1 is encrypted while the key for serv2 is not. You are asked to provide an optional password when you create the key.

Comment: Key for serv1 was created not by me. So I am not sure.
Key for serv2 was created by me. I have set password for key for serv2.

Comment: Run `ssh -v root@serv2` and it will print which key it used to log in to your server. Most likely your default identity stored in '~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa' are added on the serv2 in authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have your identity (public key) added as authorized key on serv2 in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. See `man sshd` section `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` for more information on this file.

Your default identity are stored in `~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_rsa, id_ed25519` files and similar files ending with .pub storing respective public keys. When you try to log to any remote ssh without specifying '-i' option, these are offered to remote server. If the remote server has any of these stored under their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` then you can log in with that key (i.e. without password). Because password based and public-key based are two different methods of authorizing remote user.

When you are specifying '-i' option, you are just presenting a different public key, stored in that file.

Also you can always run ssh with '-v' option to get more details about which key method/public key was accepted by the remote. Like in this example:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/nstorm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/nstorm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 blen 104
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 172.16.2.1 ([172.16.2.1]:22).
```

If you don't want to able to log in on serv2 without password when you don't set your non-default identity with '-i' option, you have to remove your default identity stored on serv2 at `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. It should be the same line as your local `~/.ssh/id_*.pub` key.